# Custom UITableViewCell using xib and autolayout doesn`t show correctly in several cells on the top

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, xib

I used custom UITableViewCell named "SCTableViewCell" and linked with "CustomCell.xib" and loading in "CenterViewController"

and when it runs, several cells on the top looks bad(like follow picture) and, after scroll down screen and up again(bad cells once disappear and appear again) it looks fine

it is custom cell class
SCTableViewCell.swift

```
class SCTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImage : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak  var descLabel : UILabel!

    func loadItem(#title: String, desc: String, image: UIImage){

        titleLabel.text = title
        descLabel.text = desc
        thumbnailImage.image = image
        self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and CenterViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    //Setting Custom Tableview Cell
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
}

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SCTableViewCell

            cell.loadItem(title: title!, desc: desc!, image: pic)
            cell.updateConstraints()

            return cell
    }
```

console shows nothing....
please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh!
I didn`t set up my cell height... ha...ha....

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 160
}
```

added in CenterViewController.swift and it works